# TryParse in C# and using the while loop

Tags: c#, while-loop, tryparse

The user Input should be within 0 to 10 and I want to use tryparse and check if the input is correct, if not then it should prompt the user again. my code is like below it only works once but if the user enters the wrong number it again executes. In this case, where should I put the loop?

```
 int number;
            bool True;
            Console.Write("Enter number between 0 t0 10: ");
            True = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number);
                while (number < 0 || number > 10)
                {
             while (True)
                    Console.Write("Enter number between 0 t0 10: ");
                    int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number);

                }

            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the correct number");

            }
            return number;
```

Comment: You need to do _something_ with the return value of **both** calls to `TryParse` - in case they type in `Bob`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd write similar code to what you already have, but I'd rename `True` to `isValid` and use a `do`/`while` loop:

```
int number;
bool isValid = false;
do
{
    Console.Write("Enter number between 0 and 10: ");

    isValid = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number) 
                  && number >= 0
                  && number <= 10;

    if (isValid)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the correct number");
    }
}
while (!isValid);
```

Better yet, do away with `isValid` altogether:

```
int number;
do
{
    Console.Write("Enter number between 0 and 10: ");
    if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number) && number >= 0 && number <= 10)
    {
        break;
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the correct number");
}
while (true);
```

Now, if the number is valid, we simply break out of the loop.

P.S. You'll see that I swaped the number conditions around to make them validity checks instead, so `<` became `>=` and `>` became `<=`.

Also, don't call a variable something like `True`. Imagine you're reading through a longer method and you come across this line (months after you've written it):

```
while (True)
```

That's an endless loop right? Oh no! It's the variable `True`, not the constant `true`. Now imagine further up you have`bool True = false;`. If you're reading quickly, you might misunderstand what the code does. Even if you're not, you have to put more mental effort into understanding what's happening.

Answer (score 2):

use do while .

```
int i = 0;

do
{
   Console.Write("Enter number between 0 t0 10: ");
   True = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number);

} while (!True);
```

Comment: int i = 0;

do
{
   Console.Write("Enter number between 0 t0 10: ");
} while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out number));

i would suggest to remove the true variable as it is not used, for error handling use bahtiyars version.